# Error with requirements file when creating docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip, requirements.txt

Note, I'm brand new to docker.

I'm trying to create a docker image of my flask app but when I run `sudo docker image build -t flask_docker .` it keeps throwing version errors at the step of installing the requirements.txt file.

Here is my docker file

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

And here is the error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Brlapi==0.8.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Brlapi==0.8.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What is the proper way to fix this error? Should I just manually go through and find which packages don't install properly and just remove them?

Comment: What platform / OS are you using to run your docker file?

Comment: I am on a CentOS server

Comment: Do you have Conda installed?

Comment: No I do not, been using pip

Comment: There is no such package: https://pypi.org/project/Brlapi/ What are you trying to install?

Comment: Yeah I'm realizing that now, not sure how that shows up in my requirements file after doing `pip freeze`. Anyways I tried removing that and several others that caused an issue and eventually it gives me an error `note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.` I'm not sure at all what to do at this point. might be time to give up.

Comment: I think you're looking for Python bindings for brltty; like these: https://pkgs.org/download/python-brlapi They cannot be installed with `pip` but with system package managers, `apt`, `dnf`, `yum` (in your case)…

Comment: Maybe try this?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-brlapi

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury `apt-get` on CenOS?

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using a Virtual environment to install packages, but for your situation try reinstalling Brlapi with

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Brlapi
```

and then `pip freeze` to get your requirements.txt

Comment: Hmm when I try that it just says no `no matching distribution found for Brlapi`

Comment: If `pip uninstall brlapi` says `WARNING: Skipping brlapi as it is not installed`, then I would either manually remove brlapi in your requirements.txt file, or just run `pip freeze` which should overwrite your requirements.txt.

Comment: Says this, `ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'Brlapi'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: Replace your RUN command with this
`RUN pip3 install --ignore-installed Brlapi && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt `

Comment: yeah it returns the original error :(

Do you think it might help if I created a virtual environment?

Comment: No I think this issue is beyond a virtual environment. Looks like Brlapi belongs to an CentOS package. Maybe try `sudo apt remove Brlapi`? Care though I'm not entirely sure if it's an important package

Comment: @Marcus `apt` on CenOS?

Comment: @phd Whoops been working with Ubuntu all day. `yum autoremove Brlapi`